# R: Convert binary categorical variables to long data format

Tags: r, reshape

```
mydata <- structure(list(id = 1:10, cafe = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
1), playground = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0), classroom = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), gender = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Female", "Male"), class = "factor"), 
    job = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Student", 
    "Teacher"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("id", "cafe", 
"playground", "classroom", "gender", "job"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")

> mydata
   id cafe playground classroom gender     job
1   1    0          1         0   Male Teacher
2   2    1          1         0   Male Student
3   3    0          1         0   Male Teacher
4   4    0          1         0   Male Student
5   5    1          1         0   Male Teacher
6   6    1          1         1   Male Teacher
7   7    0          0         1 Female Teacher
8   8    0          1         1   Male Teacher
9   9    1          1         1 Female Teacher
10 10    1          0         1   Male Student
```

My desired long format data set should look like:

```
id      response    gender        job
1     playground      Male    Teacher
2           cafe      Male    Student
2     playground      Male    Student
3     playground      Male    Teacher
...
```

Essentially, the `response` column corresponds to which of the cafe, playground, and classroom columns have a value of 1. I've looked into several examples [here](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/faq/how-can-i-reshape-my-data-in-r/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format), but they do not deal with binary data columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use do this with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
mydata %>%
    gather(response, value, cafe:classroom) %>% 
    filter(value==1) %>%
    select(id, response, gender, job)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using the `melt(data, ...)` function from the `reshape` package.

```
library(reshape)
```

First, we assign the variables that we want to keep as columns.

```
id <- c("id", "gender", "job")
```

Then, we change the wide format to long format and keep only the rows that contain a `1`.

```
df <- melt(mydata, id=id)
df[df[,5]==1,-5]
```

Then, order the data by `id`.

```
df <- df[order(df[,"id"]),]
```

Finally, we change the column name and rearrange the columns.

```
colnames(df)[4] <- "response"
df <- df[,c(1,4,2,3)]

## id   response  gender    job
## 1  playground   Male Teacher
## 2        cafe   Male Student
## 2  playground   Male Student
## 3  playground   Male Teacher
## ...
## ...
## 9   classroom Female Teacher
## 10       cafe   Male Student
## 10  classroom   Male Student
```